# Does Steiner system S(2,11, 1331) exist?

Tags: algebraic-topology, combinatorial-designs

Does the [Steiner system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) $S(2,11,1331)$ exist? 
I think it exists because $S(2, q, q^n)$ exists when $q$ is a prime power, $n\ge 2$. Confirmation will be very useful to me. A Steiner system forms a cover-free family where each block has at least one element not covered by the union of D other blocks.
I am working on topology transparent scheduling in wireless networks [1]. A schedule is a collection of time slots where a node can transmit.  One can use Steiner systems to come up with such schedules. Basically, a block in a Steiner system defines a schedule. The cover-free property ensures existence of a conflict-free slot in a block where a node's transmission will not fail. The number of blocks equals the number of nodes N. But the problem is that we may not have Steiner systems for a given (N, D). We have to use some Steiner system that is close enough at the loss of some efficiency. In this context, I was looking for some Steiner systems.

For $S(2,11,1331)$, the number of blocks = $ b =  vr/q$ where $v = 1331$, $q=11$, $r=(v-1)/(q-1)=133$ giving $b = 16093$.

1. Colbourn, Charles J., Alan CH Ling, and Violet R. Syrotiuk. "Cover-free families and topology-transparent scheduling for MANETs." Designs, Codes and Cryptography 32.1-3 (2004): 65-95.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:algebraic-topology]. I think we would all appreciate it if you shed a bit more light on the connection. Add the material to the question body, please (click the edit button under your question). It may feel unnecessary, but I see how some users think your question is a bit lacking in context. A few words about the connection would serve that need. See [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for a more verbose explanation as to why we insist on such context (or just ask :-). Welcome to MSE. Hope you enjoy the site!

Comment: I didn't check this page for sometime after posting the query yesterday. Hope I was able to describe the context well.

Comment: Thanks, DKS. Voting to reopen.

Comment: DKS, by the way. The problem you described reminds me of the one coding theorists worked a bit on some time in late 90s IIRC. It was called *optical coded division multiple access*, *optical CDMA* or some such. The idea was that user would use a shared optical channel, each repeating there bits according to personal sequence. The design game was to avoid multiple collisions. If at all feasible also between time shifted versions of two sequences (giving the option not to synchronize the clocks of all the users). Not sure if much good cae out of it, but IIRC similar constructs were studied.

Comment: Of course, the interference of other users is not as severe in a radio channel (where the channel is additive) as it might have been in a optical fibre (when there will be light if one or more user is transmitting). I'm prepared to hold some mistaken ideas about the physical characteristics of the two channels. Anyway, similar problems have been encountered in the not so distant history of telecommunications earlier, and you may want to take a look at the old solutions. Once more, the intricacies of the topology of your network may render some of my intuition useless.

Comment: (cont'd) It seems to me that you are aiming at design where a single user uses the channel only the fraction $1/q^2$ at a time. IIRC the sequences in optical CDMA covered roughly $1/q$ of the available space (a code assigned roughly $\sqrt{N}$ out of $N$ slots to a single user). That sounds actually too high a fraction to me, but I wasn't really playing that game, so I may be very wrong (I did look at the math of radio channel CDMA sequences a bit in my time).

Comment: Thanks Sir for the enlightening discussion. There are strong connections between coding theory and topology transparent scheduling (TTS). We carried out a survey sometime back [2].

Comment: (cont'd) [2] U N Kar et al. "A Survey of Topology-Transparent Scheduling Schemes in Multi-Hop Packet Radio Networks". IEEE Communications Surveys & Tutorials. 2017 Jan 1;19(4):2026-49.

Comment: (cont'd) When we adapt a Steiner system $S(t,q, v)$ for TTS, each node gets $q$ slots (a Steiner system block). Total number of slots = $v$. Each node faces conflict from max. $D$ nodes. They can be any $D$ nodes as we ignore the detailed network topology. It suffices if 1 slot in a block is conflict free (with respect of every $D$ other blocks). Then channel utilization = $1/q$.

Comment: (cont'd) But channel utilization should be computed with respect to the total number of slots. Since a node can use only one slot out of a total of $v$ slots in the frame, the avg. channel utilization per node = $1/v = 1/q^n$. Typically, $n=2$ but in my example above, $n=3$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it exists. Consider a 3-dimensional space $V$ over the field $K=\Bbb{F}_{11}$. There are $11^3=1331$ points in $V$. Any two points in $V$ determine a unique line (= a coset of a 1-dimensional subspace). The collection of all the lines in $V$ is thus the desired Steiner system.